# How to change android's button style

Tags: android, button, styles

I am creating an app and wanted to select different style(not this plain rectangles) for the buttons in my whole application is that possible? How to do it?

Comment: You should add a code snippet to explain or narrow your question focus.

Answer (score 4):

You can totally change the behaviour and appearance of buttons in android. You can use ImageButton to supply an image with it as your custom button. 
You can also set the background of button by applying an image or setting a drawable xml resource. In that xml you can define gradient colors and can modify shape, radius and corners of button.
Here is very nice tutorial about gradient buttons for android.
http://www.dibbus.com/2011/02/gradient-buttons-for-android/